# I don't understand a step in the process of solving an equation with fractions. Common denominator

Tags: linear-algebra, fractions

Context:
[This is the exercise that I had to try to solve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj0mp.png)

I couldn't figure it out and the image below is solution to this exercise.

[What I don't understand are the first and second steps in solving the equation. I don't understand how the first expression turn into its equivalent(second part)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddels.png)

in other words, how can this  $ \frac{m}{n}= 2-\frac{3x}{x+1}$ turn into that $ 2-\frac{3x}{x+1} = \frac{2(x+1)-3x}{x+1} $

If would appreciate if you could explain to me what are the thoughts and reasonings that are involved in the process to pass from the first part of the equation to the second one.
Thanks.

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: It is just adding fractions. Write $2={2(x+1)\over(x+1)}$ for a common denominator.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you for the advice. I will do that.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you

Comment: Please either delete this question or post your own answer and accept it, so that the question does not attract attention on the unanswered queue.

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks for the heads up. I did post my answer.

Comment: Use : [1] $\displaystyle 2 = \frac{2(x+1)}{x+1}$ and [2] $\displaystyle \frac{r}{t} +  \frac{s}{t} = \frac{r + s}{t}$.

Comment: Excellent. Now accept your answer.

Comment: @EthanBolker It says that I can accept it tomorrow. I can't do it before that

Answer (score 1):

What I was missing is that I was not considering the **common denominator** between step 1 and 2 (look at picture 2)

Using **common denominator** is the key to figure out why this $$ \frac{m}{n}= 2-\frac{3x}{x+1}$$ turns into that $$ 2-\frac{3x}{x+1} = \frac{2(x+1)-3x}{x+1} $$

This is the link that explains how to find and use the common denominator to solve similar problems.
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/x9e81a4f98389efdf:rational-functions/x9e81a4f98389efdf:adding-and-subtracting-rational-expressions/v/algebraic-expression-adding-fractions

I hope this will help.